# How to use preg_match to allow only specific html code snippets?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I use `preg_match()` to validate form data, and I would like to allow only specific ***html code parts***.

My code:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\söüóőúéáűíäÖÜÓŐÚÉÁŰÍÄ\-(class=\"del\")(title=\"Sample title\")(class=\"another\-class\")\(\)\/<>,.]*$/",$r)
```

That characters I allow is trivial, but I would like to allow `"` and `=` characters only in the following parts:

```
class="del"
title="Sample title"
class="another-class"
```

So the input that contains any (0 or more) of these parts **in any order** must return `true`, but any others like `class="something"` or `he said "hey"` should return `false`

Can you help with this? Thank you guys!

Comment: ??? You want to accept `class="del"` and `class="another-class"` but reject `class="something"` ??? What exactly is the variable part of your expression(s)?

Comment: that class and title tags are only strings that match with `(abcde)`. The classnames and the titles are the variable parts of the expression.

Comment: OK, thanks. I just wanted to make sure I got it right.

Comment: @kuroineko solved my problem so I must accept his "answer", but the exact question is still unanswered.

Comment: I still use preg_match, only in a way that does not require a two-lines long cryptic regexp. Since the specific patterns are known constants, I don't see the point in giving the regexp compiler a job that you can do yourself at virtually no cost. Generating dynamically a bloated regexp will very likely consume more resources and require more lines of code. Except for the regexp nazis around, I can't see who would consider that a better solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would rather delete the specific patterns from the input and then match the regular syntax.

```
$patterns = array ('class="del"', 'title="Sample title"', 'class="another-class"');

$input = 'hey man did you notice class="del"?';
if (preg_match ("/^[a-z ?]*$/", str_replace ($patterns, '', $input)))
    echo "We got a winner!";
```

If this is meant for input checking, I guess performance is only an aesthetic issue.

And that solution keeps the code fairly readable.

Comment: Oh pretty easy :) midnight plays with my mind. I made it to complicated. Thanks!